# Convert htop output to HTML

Tags: html, ncurses, htop

I wish to view the output of htop as a web page (and possibly add interactivity later on) and I expected this to be readily available (e.g. ncurses capture-screen-and-convert-to-html), but I had no luck finding such a facility. Before I start rolling my own solution, is there something else I can use?

*Edit*: I just saw [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) which is pretty much what I had in mind. Noted just in case...

Comment: Looks like the author answered to this in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file